# ImageViews Increasing Speed

Tags: java, android, debugging, imageview

I am creating a game in which obstacles come down from the top of the screen at a speed determined randomly when the game first loads.

```
public final int ranObNum1 = randomWithRange(1,30);
```

My game runs on a cycle of `gameMenu()`, `startGame()`, and `endGameMenu()`. My problem is that after each cycle, the speed increases for some reason. For example, the speed may start at 15px per 25mls, but increase whenever `startGame()` is run again.

The loop that runs every 25mls is:

```
                ob1.setY((ob1.getY()) + ranObNum1);
```

`ob1` is one of the 16 ImageViews running down the screen.

My thoughts are that `ranObNum1` would have to be somehow increasing, as the way they move is taking the current `Y` position and adding the `ranObNum`, but I don't know where that would happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need more clarification, I'll be happy to give it.

```
package com.jayrow.dodge.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.TimerTask;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Checks if the game is started.
public boolean start;

public final int[] score = {0};

public static final int ranObNum1 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum2 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum3 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum4 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum5 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum6 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum7 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum8 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum9 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum10 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum11 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum12 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum13 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum14 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum15 = randomWithRange(1,30);
public static final int ranObNum16 = randomWithRange(1,30);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainMenu();

}

public void mainMenu(){

    start = false;

    final TextView lose = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youLose);
    final TextView highScoreT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highScoreText);
    final TextView playAgainT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playAgain);
    lose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    highScoreT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    playAgainT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Retrieving views and putting them into variables.
    final ImageView ob1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle1);
    ImageView ob2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle2);
    ImageView ob3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle3);
    ImageView ob4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle4);
    ImageView ob5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle5);
    ImageView ob6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle6);
    ImageView ob7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle7);
    ImageView ob8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle8);
    ImageView ob9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle9);
    ImageView ob10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle10);
    ImageView ob11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle11);
    ImageView ob12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle12);
    ImageView ob13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle13);
    ImageView ob14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle14);
    ImageView ob15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle15);
    ImageView ob16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle16);

    //Start off with all of the obstacles invisible
    ob1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Putting the 3 titles into variables
    TextView title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView title2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.byLine);
    TextView title3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tapToPlay);

    //We want these to start off visible when the game first loads.
    title1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    title2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    title3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    title3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int eventAction = event.getAction();

            switch (eventAction) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //On button down
                    startGame();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // finger leaves the button
                    endGame();
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    score[0] = 0;
    final TextView scoreT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreView);
    scoreT.setText("" + score[0]);

}

public void endGame(){

    start = false;

    final ImageView ob1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle1);
    final ImageView ob2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle2);
    final ImageView ob3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle3);
    final ImageView ob4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle4);
    final ImageView ob5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle5);
    final ImageView ob6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle6);
    final ImageView ob7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle7);
    final ImageView ob8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle8);
    final ImageView ob9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle9);
    final ImageView ob10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle10);
    final ImageView ob11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle11);
    final ImageView ob12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle12);
    final ImageView ob13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle13);
    final ImageView ob14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle14);
    final ImageView ob15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle15);
    final ImageView ob16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle16);

    ob1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ob16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final TextView scoreT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreView);
    scoreT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final TextView lose = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youLose);
    final TextView highScoreT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highScoreText);
    final TextView playAgainT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playAgain);
    lose.setText("You Lost With a Score of " + score[0]);
    lose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    highScoreT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    playAgainT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    playAgainT.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int eventAction = event.getAction();

            switch (eventAction) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //On button down
                    mainMenu();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // finger leaves the button
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

}

//A random number generator that will make a random number within the specified range.
public static int randomWithRange(int mi, int ma)
{
    final int range = (ma - mi) + 1;
    return (int)(Math.random() * range) + mi;
}

//This is called when the user selects, "Tap to play"
public void startGame (){

    final TextView lose = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youLose);
    final TextView highScoreT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highScoreText);
    final TextView playAgainT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playAgain);
    lose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    highScoreT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    playAgainT.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Now the game has started.
    start = true;

    //We need to find the devices pixel width and height for use later in the game, since there are many different screen sizes.
    final int width = 720;
    final int height = 1280;

    //Storing and hiding the textviews.
    final TextView title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    final TextView title2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.byLine);
    final TextView title3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tapToPlay);
    title1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    title2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    title3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //Initialize and make the score visible
    final TextView scoreT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreView);
    scoreT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Naming the obstacles into variables
    final ImageView ob1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle1);
    final ImageView ob2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle2);
    final ImageView ob3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle3);
    final ImageView ob4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle4);
    final ImageView ob5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle5);
    final ImageView ob6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle6);
    final ImageView ob7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle7);
    final ImageView ob8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle8);
    final ImageView ob9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle9);
    final ImageView ob10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle10);
    final ImageView ob11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle11);
    final ImageView ob12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle12);
    final ImageView ob13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle13);
    final ImageView ob14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle14);
    final ImageView ob15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle15);
    final ImageView ob16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle16);



        //Here, all of the obstacles are set to be visible and given a random X coordinate.
        ob1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob1.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob1.setY(0);
        ob2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob2.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob2.setY(0);
        ob3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob3.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob3.setY(0);
        ob4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob4.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob4.setY(0);
        ob5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob5.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob5.setY(0);
        ob6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob6.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob6.setY(0);
        ob7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob7.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob7.setY(0);
        ob8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob8.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob8.setY(0);
        ob9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob9.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob9.setY(0);
        ob10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob10.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob10.setY(0);
        ob11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob11.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob11.setY(0);
        ob12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob12.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob12.setY(0);
        ob13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob13.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob13.setY(0);
        ob14.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob14.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob14.setY(0);
        ob15.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob15.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob15.setY(0);
        ob16.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ob16.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
        ob16.setY(0);

        //The speeds of the asteroids are randomly defined.
        final Handler h = new Handler();
        final int delay = 25; //milliseconds
        final int[] scoreDelay = {1000}; //milliseconds


        scoreDelay[0] = 1000;

        //A loop that will run ever 25 miliseconds is started.
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                //Now the obstacles fall at the speed specified earlier.
                ob1.setY((ob1.getY()) + ranObNum1);
                ob2.setY((ob2.getY()) + ranObNum2);
                ob3.setY((ob3.getY()) + ranObNum3);
                ob4.setY((ob4.getY()) + ranObNum4);
                ob5.setY((ob5.getY()) + ranObNum5);
                ob6.setY((ob6.getY()) + ranObNum6);
                ob7.setY((ob7.getY()) + ranObNum7);
                ob8.setY((ob8.getY()) + ranObNum8);
                ob9.setY((ob9.getY()) + ranObNum9);
                ob10.setY((ob10.getY()) + ranObNum10);
                ob11.setY((ob11.getY()) + ranObNum11);
                ob12.setY((ob12.getY()) + ranObNum12);
                ob13.setY((ob13.getY()) + ranObNum13);
                ob14.setY((ob14.getY()) + ranObNum14);
                ob15.setY((ob15.getY()) + ranObNum15);
                ob16.setY((ob16.getY()) + ranObNum16);

                //If one of the obstacles hits the bottom of the screen, regenerate it up top with a random X coordinate and increase score by one.
                if (ob1.getY() > height) {
                    ob1.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob1.setY(0);

                } else if (ob2.getY() > height) {
                    ob2.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob2.setY(0);

                } else if (ob3.getY() > height) {
                    ob3.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob3.setY(0);

                } else if (ob4.getY() > height) {
                    ob4.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob4.setY(0);

                } else if (ob5.getY() > height) {
                    ob5.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob5.setY(0);

                } else if (ob6.getY() > height) {
                    ob6.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob6.setY(0);

                } else if (ob7.getY() > height) {
                    ob7.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob7.setY(0);

                } else if (ob8.getY() > height) {
                    ob8.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob8.setY(0);

                } else if (ob9.getY() > height) {
                    ob9.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob9.setY(0);

                } else if (ob10.getY() > height) {
                    ob10.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob10.setY(0);

                } else if (ob11.getY() > height) {
                    ob11.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob11.setY(0);

                } else if (ob12.getY() > height) {
                    ob12.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob12.setY(0);

                } else if (ob13.getY() > height) {
                    ob13.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob13.setY(0);

                } else if (ob14.getY() > height) {
                    ob14.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob14.setY(0);

                } else if (ob15.getY() > height) {
                    ob15.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob15.setY(0);

                } else if (ob16.getY() > height) {
                    ob16.setX(randomWithRange(0, width));
                    ob16.setY(0);

                }

                ob1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int eventAction = event.getAction();
                        switch (eventAction) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                //On button down
                                endGame();
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });


                h.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);


        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (start = true) {

                    score[0] = score[0] + 1;
                }
                scoreT.setText("" + score[0]);


                h.postDelayed(this, scoreDelay[0]);
            }
        }, scoreDelay[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code? Perhaps the entire class file? There's not much we can do without more information.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're not cancelling the loop that you start when you call `startGame()`. When you call `endGame()`, the views are still being translated down the screen because the loop is still going on, so when you call `startGame()` again, each view is translated *twice*, one time for the old loop that wasn't cancelled before, and another time for the current loop.

Besides this, you should consider reworking your code using some sort of arrays or lists so you don't need to keep track and manipulate a gazillion instance variables. First, set a tag for each of your views in the xml layout such that your tags follow a specific naming convention (object1, object2, object3). Also, set an id on your root view in your layout. Then, change this:

```
 //Retrieving views and putting them into variables.
final ImageView ob1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle1);
ImageView ob2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle2);
ImageView ob3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle3);
ImageView ob4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle4);
ImageView ob5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle5);
ImageView ob6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle6);
ImageView ob7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle7);
ImageView ob8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle8);
ImageView ob9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle9);
ImageView ob10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle10);
ImageView ob11 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle11);
ImageView ob12 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle12);
ImageView ob13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle13);
ImageView ob14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle14);
ImageView ob15 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle15);
ImageView ob16 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obstacle16);

//Start off with all of the obstacles invisible
ob1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
ob16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

To this:

```
ArrayList<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
View rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
ArrayList<View> touchables = rootView.getTouchables();
for(int i = 0; i < touchables.size(); i++)
{
   View touchable = touchables.get(i);
   if(touchable.getTag().toString().contains("object")
   {
      imageViews.add((ImageView) touchable);
   }
}
```

You can then manipulate this list far easier by iterating over it whenever you want to set properties such as view positions and visibility states.

Comment: I invalidated the runnables using `h[0].removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`. Thanks so much, your solution worked great!